# Use a typescript file for Jest configuration

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

To configure jest, it is possible to use a JSON file or a js file, as said in the documentation:

> Jest's configuration can be defined in the package.json file of your project, or through a jest.config.js file or through the --config  option

Is there a way for me to use a typescript file instead of a javascript file?

Comment: highly unlikely, configs need to be loaded before build tools like typescript kick in. However, you can have a typescript file that compiles to a js file in place. You will have to manually run `tsc` on the file everytime you change it. But why do you need typescript for a config file in the first place?

Comment: I do not really need it, but I was asking myself how to do it. When I can choose, I prefer using ts over js. Since I'm using other ts modules, it would have been easier for me to have a ts file.

Comment: If your config for Jest needs to import other modules you're probably overcomplicating it

Comment: ts has no real values for configs as configs are mostly structured json and schema checking will still be provided in js files by your ide. But yeah if you really want use the standalone typescript compiler `tsc`.

Comment: I'm also using the configuration file to execute some code that I need to launch before my tests. I'm doing this way because Jest does not have a "before all suites".